# Trying to set buying price of an object according to rank using php

Tags: php

I am trying to price an object based on ranking.  My problem is that if the object has no ranking it is going to the next tier.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
switch ($amazonResult['SalesRank']) {
case ($amazonResult['SalesRank'] < 1 || trim($amazonResult['SalesRank'])===''|| !isset($amazonResult['SalesRank']) || $amazonResult['SalesRank']=== null):
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) *<some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break; 
case ($amazonResult['SalesRank'] > 0 && $amazonResult['SalesRank'] <= 15000):
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) * <some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break;
default:
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) * <some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break;
}
```

How do I get it to find the ranking if the ranking is either empty, null, or 0?

$amazonResult['SalesRank'] could be empty, and is the value that needs to be compared in each case.  This variable is pulled from a query and is run every time an item is to be priced

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question - is $amazonResult['SalesRank'] the variable that is potentially empty?  What result do you want if there is no rank?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($amazonResult['SalesRank']) || empty(trim($amazonResult['SalesRank'])) {
    // case if the variable is empty.
} else if($amazonResult['SalesRank'] < 1) {
    // some "valid" value
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) *<some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break;
} else if($amazonResult['SalesRank'] > 0 && $amazonResult['SalesRank'] <= 15000) {
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) * <some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break;
} else {
    $Price=((float) $lowestAmazonPrice) * <some percent to pay>;
    $payPrice = round($Price, 0);  //to round the price up or down to the nearest $
    break;
}
```

The value after `case` should be constant so that you can compair that with the variable in `switch`.

Your problem is that your case construct will return true or false which is may be not equal to `$amazonResult['SalesRank']`.